# How can I use the --rpc-cors flag properly?

Tags: substrate-node-template, json-rpc, cors

I m attempting to use the `--rpc-cors flag` to specify certain domains that are allowed to send requests to my chain (localhost - substrate-node-template). However, regardless of how I use this flag, I am still able to access my blockchain on https://polkadot.js.org/. Is this the correct `flag` for blocking external access? Am I using this `flag` correctly, or should I combine it with another one?
[image: Example using "./target/release/node-template --force-authoring --alice --tmp --rpc-cors=https://mywebsite.com,https://myothersite.com"]

Comment: I believe you can access it because if you were running both https://polkadot.js.org/ and the node on the same computer, they share the same origin.